# My application is not working (not launching) with Kitkat or lower versions

Tags: android, apk, build.gradle

i complied it with sdk 23 and tried to compile it with sdk 16 but errors pops up.. i cant build it with sdk 16.
i also tried changing target sdk and minimum sdk.
application works well with Lollipop and marshmallow. 
but lower versions like kitkat gingerbread not opening. always force quitting.

my Build.gradle(app) File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.braveheartcreations.wifiexplorer"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 17
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
            }
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.00'
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'net.vrallev.android:cat:1.0.2'
    provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
    compile 'com.karumi:dexter:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.9.0'
    compile files('libs/ftp4j-1.7.2.jar')
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.1'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
```

Comment: Any chance to reveal the error messages?

Comment: sorry. actually i own only marshmallo and lollipop devices. while i try to install the app in kitkat its not opening. it force quitting. this config is ok with all devices?

Answer (score 0):

You can't install this application into Android 4.0.4 and lower versions devices because the minSdkVersion is 16.For the kitkat device, you must paste the log here.

By the way,when you use compatibility with JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8, you must enable the jack.

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
```